# Need some feedback: Customizing JBoss-Portal with CSS

Tags: css, portlet, jboss-portal

As a Web-designer, I've been asked to evaluate the customization of an instance of JBoss-portal. My knowledge about JBoss-portal is very poor but I know that with such portals it's sometimes (always?) very hard to manipulate and modify layouts and themes.

Can somebody tell me if it's possible to customize JBoss-Portal simply via a new CSS stylesheet? Some feedbak and examples of what can/can't be done would help!

For example:

- Is it possible to customize the global layout of the portal?
- Is *portal_style.css* the only file to modify?

What I need here is not a Yes or No that's true, but some feedback from someone who knows how to customize JBoss-Portal and how far I can go.

Thanks!

Comment: What is easy and what not is fully dependent on your knowledge and experience. And much more it depends on your will to learn new stuff and how good your comprehension of that stuff is. So a question if something is easy can only be answered totally subjective.

Comment: Any screenshots? Any specifications? What kind of customization? Without providing any details and expecting an answer is like expecting us to read your minds! We are not mind readers!!

Comment: Hi, I understand these comments but my problem here is to evaluate what kind of customization can be done to JBoss-Portal in order to make some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally found an interesting HowTo PDF Guide [here](http://jbossworld.com/2008/downloads/pdf/friday/11-1150am_JBoss_Portal_How-To_Guide_Peter_Johnson.pdf)

I hope this will help other users ;)